# how to change the url of an anchor link that doesn't have an id or class using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I don't have access to the html document that hosts piece of the code. The anchor links are incorrect and users are unable to access information and tools. The anchor link sits inside of an `<h1>` tag which sits inside of a `table`, that sits inside of a `div`. Now the div is the only thing that has an ID, and I can't add jQuery to this page wrapper because it has been applied to 1000+ pages so I don't want to break anything.

HTML:

```
<div id="dashboard-home-content">
    <div id="bd-what-next" class="clearfix">
        <h2 id="msg_cat_what_next_question">What to do next?</h2>
        <div id="what-next-answer">Customize your Personal Page with a story about why you are raising funds for this cause.</div>
    </div>
    <!-- bd-what-next -->
    <div class="ux-block2" id="bd-org-html">
        <!-- TODO: Message Catalog this, Fix language -->
        <div id="organization_message">
            <table style="width: 100%;" border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h1><a href="change this url" target="_blank"><img src="../cco/images/content/pagebuilder/PC_FAQ_image.jpg" border="0" alt="Personal page image"><br>Participant Centre FAQ</a></h1>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h1><a href="change this url" target="_blank"><img src="../cco/images/content/pagebuilder/PC_pic_image.jpg" border="0" alt="Personal page image"><br>Photo resize tool</a></h1>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h1><a href="change this url" target="_blank"><img src="../cco/images/content/pagebuilder/PC_fundraising_image.jpg" border="0" alt="Personal page image"><br>Fundraising FAQ</a></h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

I know with jQuery I can look for a specific element that has something specific in it to add a class, like

```
$('td:contains("As part of your registration you will receive update emails and support from this program.")').addClass("td_regDetails");
```

But I don't know how to do that with JavaScript.

I'm thinking if there's a way to add a class or id to that anchor link, I could do something like

```
var pcfaq = document.getElementById('wrongLinkOne');
pcfaq.href= "[[S8:PC_FAQ_updated.html]]"
```

(the S8 renders the html link).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry but where is the `wrongLinkOne` id?

Comment: Just use `document.querySelector`, use an appropriate selector and modify the element as you see fit.

Comment: @FrancoScarpa sorry the wrongLinkOne was just something I made up as an example of what I'd do if I could figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll()` to find all the `a` tags inside `td`. Loop over them, check if the text contains what you want, and change the `href`.

```
document.querySelectorAll("td a").forEach(el => {
    if (a.textContent.includes("As part of your registration you will receive update emails and support from this program.")) {
        a.href = "[[S8:PC_FAQ_updated.html]]";
    }
});
```

Comment: awesome! thank you so much. I googled "how to change anchor link with javascript" and "find element that contains text using javascript" but I couldn't find anything that made sense to me lol. This is perfect Barmar thank you